# Documentation, api-documentation and software-documentation tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've stumbled on the [software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation) and [api-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-documentation) tags today, but funnily enough, there was no generic "documentation" tag that could gather all-documentation related issues.

So, i've tried adding it ([documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation)) in my latest question. It makes sense to have a tag that's more generic (an hypernim, rather than a synonym) to me; but I'm not completely sure.

Is it fine or is it useless?

Comment: My concern with a [tag:documentation] tag is that it would be used instead of (or in addition to) the [tag:citation] tag.  Or something else regarding sources.  Perhaps [tag:instructions] or something similar would work better?

Answer (score 4):

There are other types of documentation, like assembly instructions, directions for using equipment, and so on.  My thought when I created [software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation) was that doc for software might have important, different properties from those others, but I'm not sure that's true.  Possibly we could promote that tag to [documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation), pending a need for specific subcategories.

[api-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-documentation) is different enough that I want to keep that tag, for findability if nothing else.  API documentation is (usually) generated from comments embedded in source code; that's pretty different from writing free-form text.  Even when it's not generated from code (REST APIs, for example), there are usually API-specific tools, standards, and requirements.  When you're looking for information about that stuff, having a tag helps find it in the larger collection of documentation questions.

For a long time we had a zillion different genres and forms for fiction and a single [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing) tag.  Technical writing has different types too, so that's what I started to build out here.  But I was definitely reacting to the questions we have, not following a grand plan, so I don't object to tweaks.

All *that* said, though, we *do* have a little targeted advertising specifically in the software area, so maybe it's worth keeping [software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation).

Comment: To be fair, I would keep the specific ones too; I totally agree with your reasoning on the matter.

Comment: Yeah, after writing all that I think I want to keep software-documentation (and api-documentation).  I expect to see tags for other kinds of documentation arise.  All of these (so far) are also technical-writing, which has a tag, so I don't know that we need documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason to have both the overarching tag, **and** the specific tags. To me it makes sense to either have [software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation) and [api-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-documentation) **or** to have [documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation). My reasoning is: is there any question to which [documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) would be applied, but not one of the more specific ones? If the general tag will *always* be used with one of the two more specific ones, why have it?

However, I have no opinion on whether we should have the one overarching tag, or the two separate ones. I'm not sufficiently tech-savvy to understand the difference between them.

Comment: While I agree in general, there are many types of documentation that are not software or API documentation. "How to assemble this IKEA bookshelf" is documentation; as is an in-depth technical description of a programming language or web service or a user's manual for a piece of software. So there are clearly cases where [tag:documentation] could apply, but not either of [tag:software-documentation] and [tag:api-documentation].

Comment: @aCVn ah, my logic + additional information = different conclusion. OK.